# PHP - Variables not replaced in PDO connection string

Tags: php, pdo

Strange issue - I have a live copy of a database class (using PDO) that works fine. I have a copy on my machine using WAMPServer which does not.

The connection string is as follows (a snippet from the class):

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'password';
$dbname = 'my_dbname';

self::$_instance = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname', $user, $pass);
```

The error messages I get are:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in <path> on line 41

Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is kn (trying to connect via tcp://$host:3306) in <path> on line 41
```

I have no idea why it's not working locally whereas online its fine. If I change the line itself to the below it works fine:

```
self::$_instance = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_dbname', $user, $pass);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: How it will replace the variables mate when you use the single quote?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use double quotes `new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);` otherwise the variables will not inserted into the string. Another way could be

```
new PDO(sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', $host, $dbname), $user, $pass);
```

Comment: That works - thanks. But why does it work live but not locally using singles?

Comment: maybe there is a fallback server and database defined on the live system.

Answer (score 1):

```
self::$_instance = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
```

You need to use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not parsed with single quotes. you have to enclose them with double quotes.

```
 self::$_instance = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answer above don't work by me. I use:

```
new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$dbname, $user, $pass);
```