# WAMP: 'No such host is known' when trying to connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, apache, wamp, vhosts

I got this error :

```
Warning: PDO::__construct() [<a href='pdo.--construct'>pdo.--construct</a>]: [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (trying to connect via tcp://1:3306) in Z:\work\...
```

My localhost/phpmyadmin works fine but I can't access localhost or 127.0.0.1 , I get a blank page with "Forbidden : You don't have permission to access / on this server."

I have nothing else running on my port 80

I modified my httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "z:/work/"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "z:/work/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Also added in my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<Directory C:/Users/Alex/Documents/GitHub>
Order Deny,Allow   
Allow from all 
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory Z:/work>
Order Deny,Allow   
Allow from all 
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "Z:\work\mysite"
    ServerName bullseye.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>   
DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\GitHub\Myproject" 
ServerName framework.local 
</VirtualHost>
```

And my phpmyadmin.conf is as follow

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/" 

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The code giving the error :

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$database = 'mydatabase';
$this->db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $database . ';host=' .$host . ';charset=utf8', $user, $pass);
```

I get the same error using mysql or msqli instead of PDO

Comment: phpMyAdmin is just a client program, it doesn't really have to do with where the mySQL server runs.  Can you show what code you are using to connect to the database, and do you really have a database server running on localhost?

Comment: Yes I have a database on my localhost (created via localhost/phpmyadmin) I get the same error if I try to connect via mysql or PDO , I am currenylu using this :  $this->db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $database . ';host=' .$host . ';charset=utf8', $user, $pass); where host = 'localhost' user = 'root' and password = ''

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are doing it the way you show? Because [PHP - Variables not replaced in PDO connection string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5950512)

Comment: 100% sure , same problem if I use $this->db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydatabase;host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to:

Undo all your changes to httpd.conf. Your changes have removed all knowledge Apache has of the WAMP homepage i.e. localhost.
Comment out the include of the virtual hosts config and check you can again access the WAMP homepage.

Make sure that WAMP is 'OffLine', this will keep the C:\ drive and c:\wamp folder secure.

Now to your Virtual hosts definitions:

In order to keep the wamp homepage working the first entry should be as below, note the Directory block should be part of the definition of the VirtualHost and the security definition makes sure you can only access the wamp homepage from 127.0.0.1(localhost)

```
###must be first so the the wamp menu page loads
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@homemail.net
    DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Each VHOST you define should contain its own security settings like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "Z:\work\mysite"
    ServerName bullseye.local
    ServerAlias bullseye.local
    AllowOverride All
    <Directory "Z:\work\mysite">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>   
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\GitHub\Myproject" 
    ServerName framework.local 
    ServerAlias www.framework.local
    <Directory "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\GitHub\Myproject">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Uncomment the Include in https.conf for your vhosts definitions and try accessing you other projects again.

I assume you have made the required changes to your c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file to include a reference to all you virtual hosts? If not the hosts file should look like this :-

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1  framework.local
127.0.0.1  bullseye.local
```

Comment: This , with the help of this http://www.webtrunghieu.info/web/solve-the-denied-access-problem-when-using-wamp-server-2-on-windows-8-/ resolved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Please dont use the solution you found on that blog, it is so bad its dangerous. That allows access to your whole C drive to any would be hacker that manages to break into your sites and also allows anyone access to your phpMyAdmin, a real bad idea as thats complete access to all your databases. If you were getting that problem its due to having IPV4 and IPV6 available on your PC. Instead try changing 'Listen *:80 to Listen 0.0.0.0:80 in your httpd.conf file, and replacing the deny security on c:\wamp and the phpmyadmin alias.

Answer (score 1):

My concern is this:

```
DocumentRoot "z:/work/"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "z:/work/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Unfortunately I don't have time to test this before I suggest it... but if DocumentRoot is `z:/work/` then Directory `/` is also `z:/work/` and you have set that to `deny all` and `override none`. Later trying to change the permission with `Directory "z:/work/"` would be considered an override and therefore not be applied? I suggest you try changing the AllowOverride to all or removing the deny all from / before you spend too much time hunting down other possible solutions.